# google weather api links need human authentication

Tags: api, weather

I developed a weather app using [google weather](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=lincoln) API
but from today it stopped working.

When I tried to access the weather API using location through browser it asks for human authentication.

How can my app work when it is like this? Is there a way to bypass the authentication process?

Comment: What do you mean with "human authentication" ? do you need to fill captcha or does it ask you to login ?

Comment: [Searching for Google weather](http://googleweather.riaforge.org/) shows that the API is not public, that's why it changed ...

Comment: This is an unofficial and unsupported API used by iGoogle. Since Google has announced that iGoogle will be shut down next year (http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/07/spring-cleaning-in-summer.html), you may want to rely on a different API.

Comment: FWIW, My application using the "Secret" igoogle weather feed just stopped working in the last few days as well. I switched to the NOAA feed, and the adjustments couldnt have gone smoother. http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXML.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very odd behavior...I wonder if it has something to do with headers that are passed along as when I try loading the API url in Chrome, Unsupported API...or if I do same URL in Firefox, works just fine.

It's also worth noting that I tried setting up an Apache Proxy to Google's weather service by placing the following two lines in a separate Web Server's apache config and referenced the API via www.domain.com/weather/api?weather=Chicago and it still works...so that's my workaround for now:

ProxyPassReverse /weather/ http://www.google.com/ig/

ProxyPass /weather/ http://www.google.com/ig/

Answer (score 2):

Try to change domain, ex: http://www.google.ca/ig/api?weather=Sondrio . It works (for now :D).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is out of use from now on

Even using .CA it returns Unsupported API randomly.

Pity

Comment: Any idea why it is randomly saying Unsupported API?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, interesting, Google seems to send back random "Unsupported API" responses if the request is missing the cookies that the browsers (tested with Chrome and Firefox) are including with requests to the inofficial weather URL.

I've fixed my application by copying the entire "Cookie:" header I found when I ran the request in Firefox with Firebug's "Net" tab enabled.

Not sure where on .google.com the browser got the cookies from yet, I presume from using a personalized service like gmail.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a *weather API* that works right now, I have a suggestion…

Try Metwit [Weather API](http://metwit.com/developers/), it's new but sounds very cool…
This api is really simple to use because it use standards that are available nowadays, like JSON and REST.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this new api this has the same xml structure of google weather api

http://en.previmeteo.com/professionals/google-weather-api.php