# How to get 5 days weather forecast from Yahoo Weather

Tags: android, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

I am developing android project, in that i have to show the particular city's weather forecast. First i thought to achieve it through the Google Weather API, then as stated by "Jason Hall" in the **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557693/google-weather-api-links-need-human-authentication)**, so iGoogle going to shut down. Then i turned my view to Yahoo Weather API, by googled i got this **[link](http://code.google.com/p/yahooweatherandroid/)**. So i got the weather forecast for particular location, now i want to get it for next 5 days, i tried **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399422/weather-forcasts-from-yahoo-weather-api)**.But it only returns for single day only How to achieve it. Answers welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo weather API doesn't support third parameter  it only will response for WOEID and U. ,But yahoo provide this option only for U.S . , if you want to get 5 days forecast means, better you can try other 3rd party API's like Accuweather , Sky etc..

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you provide other 3rd party API's link to get it.

Comment: before asking questions , you must google it once. there are various resource available in google. try this, http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=361