# How to get Weekly Weather forecast from yahoo API

Tags: android, yahoo-weather-api

I want to get Weekly weather forecast from yahoo api

I'm using this API and try to give d=4 in parameter but it's not working,
is there any alternative API or I am missing some thing ?

```
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=" + woeidNumber
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: define "it's not working"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: 
http://soup.metwit.com/post/47181933854/an-alternative-to-yahoo-weather-api

I would recommend Metwit [weather API](http://metwit.com/weather-api/). It's an easy to use fully REST API and it's free to use for many reasonable uses.

(Full disclosure: I am a founder of Metwit. Feel free to ask me for further details)

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo weather API doesn't support third parameter it only will response for WOEID and U. ,But yahoo provide this option only for U.S . , if you want to get 5 days forecast means, better you can try other 3rd party API's like Accuweather , Sky etc..

For more info refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760967/how-to-get-5-days-weather-forecast-from-yahoo-weather?rq=1)